# How do I shuffle data and insert to database

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with shuffle.
I have a 2 data (Test1,Test2) and I want to save it to database using shuffle but it's always return same value it is not randomizing. Here is my code.

```
$item = $data[9];
$str_arr = explode(",", $item); // item to search
$collectKey = collect($str_arr);
$iteratedData = $collectKey->shuffle();

foreach ($iteratedData as $itr) { // this will save and shuffle value (Test1,Test2)
    $sales->Monday1 = $itr;
    $sales->Monday2 = $itr;
    $sales->Monday3 = $itr;
    $sales->Tuesday1 = $itr;
    $sales->Tuesday2 = $itr;
    $sales->Tuesday3 = $itr;
    $sales->Wednesday1 = $itr;
    $sales->Wednesday2 = $itr;
    $sales->Wednesday3 = $itr;
    $sales->Thursday1 = $itr;
    $sales->Thursday2 = $itr;
    $sales->Thursday3 = $itr;
    $sales->Friday1 = $itr;
    $sales->Friday2 = $itr;
    $sales->Friday3 = $itr;
    $sales->Saturday1 = $itr;
    $sales->Saturday2 = $itr;
    $sales->Saturday3 = $itr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to iterate your properties as well in order to assign them different values.

```
$properties = ['Monday1', 'Monday2', 'Monday3', 'Tuesday1', 'Tuesday2',
    'Tuesday3', 'Wednesday1', 'Wednesday2', 'Wednesday3', 'Thursday1',
    'Thursday2', 'Thursday3', 'Friday1', 'Friday2', 'Friday3', 'Saturday1',
    'Saturday2', 'Saturday3'];

$i = 0;
foreach($iteratedData as $itr){ // this will save and shuffle value (Test1,Test2)
    $sales->{$properties[$i++]} = $itr;
}
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for the solution, I have an error "Array to string conversion"

Comment: @KletoRalphFuentesSalvo  sorry, you need curly brace over the property.

Comment: It returns error, your iteration is working but I want to save it to database after the loop. Is it possible?

Comment: @KletoRalphFuentesSalvo of course, just call $sales->save(); after the loop

Comment: Sometimes it return null.

Comment: try inspecting your data, it could be not being extracted properly

Comment: I was thinking, what if we count the properties first then, the value count of the properties will do the same count on array loop? to avoid null data. Is this possible? Sorry I need help on this, I am a beginner in programing. Just Bear with me. Thank you

Comment: since $properties is just an unchanged array, it will always have the same count(), so you could just count your $iterateData which can be varied

Answer (score 0):

```
$iteratedData = $collectKey->shuffle()->all();
```

[Read More about shuffle](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-shuffle)

Comment: collection objects are iteratable. all() is not necessary.

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.